# Math font too italicized

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I like how the MathJax settings are no longer images *in principle*.

However I find the font Chrome is using to be a lot less readable than the images we used to see before, even on zoom in

[image]

Mostly its due to the thinness of the characters coupled with too much italicizing.

Are people happy with it?  Did they like the images better?  I did.

Is there a way to have mathjax render-mode (old school *image* or new style html/css) an option?

Comment: bobobobo: you shouldn't do that. Next time re-upload the picture using `ctrl+g` and pasting the image link using "from the web" with the `.stack` stripped from the old link. See [Jeff's answer here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2483/broken-imgur-links) for an explanation why.

Answer (score 7):

Doesn't look that way for me on Chrome 10, Windows 7 x64:

[image]

Are you using an OS that doesn't do character anti-aliasing like Windows XP?

[Prove the reduction formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30595/prove-the-reduction-formula)

Comment: Same O/S/config. Actually, I turned off "smooth edges of screen fonts" in System Properties/Performance Options.  (I don't use antialiasing for normal text because I find it uncomfortable).  When I turn it on, the mathjax does look better. Suppose I can't have the best of both worlds, huh

Comment: I don't think its XP related since on XP SP3 I see the same formula as do you, not the OP's. It may be that the OP is using a low DPI monitor. I think this is the same problem that I [recently reported](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1889/242) about the recent font changes being a big step backwards. This change should be reverted. It's so bad I cannot even bear looking at some renderings.

Comment: @bobobobo: Nowadays, I can no longer stand seeing non-anti-aliased text, to me it's surprising that you actually preferred non-anti-aliased text. Have you tried tuning ClearType parameters? http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/step1.aspx

Comment: I did. I'd rather increase the screen font size than have ClearType blur it. I was brought up in the 90's, so I'm most comfortable with jaggy text.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu + Firefox 5:
[image]

I think you should try tweaking your system's font smoothing, it should be available since as early as Windows 2000 and the first MacOS X.

You might need to use 3rd-party tools for this, though.